# Не рисуются фигуры на JFrame(JPanel) при Layout(null)

Tags: java, swing, awt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно, чтобы на одном `JFrame` отображались кнопки и фигуры(стрелки/линии). Для расположения кнопок задаю `layout null`, но при этом не отрисовываются элементы из метода `paintComponent`. Если `layout` по умолчанию, то линия отрисовывается, но расползается расположение кнопок, как мне не надо. Как отрисовать фигуру(линию, в частности) при `layout null` ?
Цель: реализация подобного алгоритма https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Jeremy.Jones/vivio/caches/MESI.htm

```
public class Check extends JPanel {

public Check() {
}

public void draw(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null); // ??????
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setSize(600,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawLine(10,10,500,500);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Check inst = new Check();
    inst.draw();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно немного изменить подход, а именно разбить панель для отрисовки компонентов и графики на несколько.
В примере ниже:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Check {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MyButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new MyDrawPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(600, 600);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            });
        }

        static class MyButtonPanel extends JPanel {
            private JButton button = new JButton("1");
            private JButton button1 = new JButton("2");
            private JButton button2 = new JButton("3");
            private JButton button3 = new JButton("4");
            private JButton button4 = new JButton("5");

            public MyButtonPanel() {
                add(button);
                add(button1);
                add(button2);
                add(button3);
                add(button4);
            }
        }

        static class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
            public MyDrawPanel() {
                setLayout(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponents(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.drawLine(10, 10, 500, 500);
            }
        }
    }
```

Панель с кнопками это одна панель, а с линией другая.

UPD Пример на одной панели:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Check {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MyDrawPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(600, 600);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            });
        }

        static class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
            private JButton button = new JButton("1");
            private JButton button1 = new JButton("2");
            private JButton button2 = new JButton("3");
            private JButton button3 = new JButton("4");
            private JButton button4 = new JButton("5");

            MyDrawPanel() {
                setLayout(null);
                button.setSize(50, 20);
                button.setLocation(10, 10);
                add(button);
                button1.setSize(50, 20);
                button1.setLocation(40, 40);
                add(button1);
                button2.setSize(50, 20);
                button2.setLocation(50, 50);
                add(button2);
                button3.setSize(50, 20);
                button3.setLocation(80, 80);
                add(button3);
                button4.setSize(50, 20);
                button4.setLocation(10, 10);
                add(button4);
            }

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponents(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.drawLine(10, 10, 500, 500);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Да, я думал об этом. Но решил спросить, вдруг есть другой вариант. Получается, если смотреть ту схему, что по ссылке, мне нужно создавать 4 панели для отображения стрелок и добавлять их на frame? При этом frame может быть с layout = null, так как мы уже рисуем на отдельных панелях. Так? Скрин, как я это вижу, прикрепил к вопросу.

Comment: Если вы хотите нарисовать один в один, то размещать кнопки Вам необходимо вручную на той же панели где и стрелки. Добавил в ответ все на одной панели

Comment: Хорошо, но что тогда с layout? Если я сделаю null, то стрелки не отрисуются, если буду использовать стандартный, то при масштабировании кнопки будут расползаться, а стрелки оставаться на месте. На тех координатах, которые я им задал.

Comment: Здесь вступает в дело Ваша логика и Ваш диспетчер компоновки, который должен сам располагать компоненты. То есть по хорошему, Вам необходимо Ваши стрелки сделать компонентами и располагать их по Вашей логике. Если я ответил на Ваш основной вопрос, отметь те как ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, спасибо, так понятнее. Отметил:)

Comment: Еще немного побеспокою Вас. Как реализовать пересечение стрелок, те, что в центре? Неужели никак невозможно вставить в центр JPanel  и в ней через указание координат рисовать стрелки, без layout. Ибо как с помощь layout поместить два объекта поверх друг друга так, чтоб второй не перекрыл первый я не понимаю. Спасибо

Comment: Полагаю, использовать OverlayLayout. Так?:)

Comment: Немного не понял вопроса. В чем именно проблема с перекрываемостью?

Comment: С использованием OverlayLayout проблем нет. Просто в тех нескольких статьях, на которые я натыкался про него не было упомянуто. Если использоваться какой либо другой, то когда я пытаюсь добавить вторую стрелку на JPanel, она перекрывала предыдущую. В итоге отображалась только последняя. Сейчас проблем нет.